# A procedural asphalt material with inset stones

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural, shader-nodes

I'm trying to make a realistic looking asphalt texture, with the little stones of about 3 different colours set into it.

Here's what my current attempt looks like:
[image]

And here's my reference:
[image]

There are a few problems that I'd appreciate help with:

1. The stones are too rounded, I've tried adding more noise textures to add some distortion to them but nothing manages to look like the angular stones in the reference.
2. The stones are all one colour, but in the reference some are brown, some grey, some reddish. I could add some coloured voronoi to the result, but the result would have more than one colour per stone.

Can anyone offer some advice or tweaks? I've added the blend file here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

False-color:

[image]

Using the same Voronoi node for the rock/asphalt mask (rocks made rougher with noise) and rocks in three different colors may be closer to what you're going for.

[image]